# Is it possible to call BlazeDS from Java?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, blazeds

Basically I'm trying to proxy some web services locally (for reasons I won't go into now) and then have a Java application call it.

I'm looking at BlazeDS since it seems to do just this, mostly to avoid the crossDomain.xml file required by Flex to call web services. However I can't seem to find any reference on how to connect through a Java client (probably using Axis2).

***Update:*** What I'm looking for is really just a way to adjust the end point so that I can point to virtual instance to get around a VPN issue.

Any suggestions, and especially tutorials, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure that I understand. Do you want to change the destination defined in proxy-config.xml dynamically? It will help if you can describe your problem a little bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class called AMFConnection is available in BlazeDS from build 3.1.0.2602, written by Mete Atamel, one of the engineers working on BlazeDS. The basic purpose of this class is to allow a Java application to talk to a remoting destination. It can serialize/deserialize AMF messages using the BlazeDS classes.

Here is the spec : [link text](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Java+AMF+Client)

I hope this helps.

Comment: What I'm actually looking for is not another way to connect, but rather just to be able to change the endpoints